# Density curve in R - AUC bigger than 1

Tags: r, auc, density-estimation

correct me if I'm wrong but I was expecting the area under the curve should be 1 for a probability density function.
Can anybody explain why it's not always the case when using the `density` function in R?
Here is some example code to demponstrate it:

```
x <- rlnorm(1000000)

adjust <- seq(from = 0.001, to = 1, by = 0.001)

auc <- sapply(adjust, function(a) {
  d <- density(x, adjust = a)
  sum(d$y * (d$x[2]-d$x[1]))
})

plot(auc ~ adjust, type = "l")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is discretization error. You specify a too small bandwidth for the number of values estimated (by default n = 512). Compare `d <- density(x, adjust = 0.001, n = 1e6); sum(d$y * (d$x[2]-d$x[1]))` with `d <- density(x, adjust = 0.001, n = 512); sum(d$y * (d$x[2]-d$x[1]))`

Comment: @Roland: I see, I misunderstood the bandwidth parameter for controlling the width from x[1] to x[2]... (which can be changed with setting n instead....).